# Need help in designing the msyql database for a hospital management sytem

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a hospital management application on a national level i.e. all the hospitals from my country will be using it.

So I need to know how should I design the database.

There will be hospitals and patients which are most concerned here.
How should I have these 2 things in a mysql database. I mean to say is it good to have patients from all the hospitals in one table and hospitals in other table and link them up by foreign key.

Check these images below
[image: Hospital Table]

[image: Patients Table]

```
// Save Patient - Personal Details
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PATIENTS_PERSONAL ."";
$sql .= "(hospital_id, title, first_name, middle_name, last_name, date_of_birth, age, sex, occupation, marital_status, religion, tribe, preferred_language, datecreated, datemodified) VALUES";
$sql .= "($hospital_id, '$title', '$first_name', '$middle_name', '$last_name', '$date_of_birth', $age, '$sex', '$occupation', '$marital_status', '$religion', '$tribe', '$preferred_language', now(), now())";
$query = $mysql->query($sql);
```

I have done this so far but I am concerned as once the number of records grow, what will be the issues I am going to face.

A patient table should be in millions once the application goes live. So I need suggestions about how ideally it should be designed so that there wont be any issue of dealing with large no of records and other common database issues etc.?

Comment: Unless your country happens to be the Pitcairn Islands, you probably ought to consider employing a professional with experience of similar projects to work on an application of such sensitivity and importance.

Comment: Don't forget there are regulations, depending on your country, on how patient data should be stored.

Answer (score 0):

1. All required indexes must be in place
2. Go back to RDBMS concepts of normalization & de-normalization to decide what level of normalization will help.
3. Ensure you have adequate field size - I see that certain fields are too long and certain too short
4. Don't have redundant fields (example - age and DOB)
5. many fields could be null. Check that otherwise your first record itself will fail
6. Other issues are DBA related like DB sizing, features, etc. Check with your DBA on that

Comment: Having large tables is not unheard of - I have seen single oracle table having 2 million records and few such tables in single DB instance. The design is paramount to get quick data. As @elrado mentioned, triggers should help in audit tasks

But I am curious - the interface seems web based panel. If you using this in a hosting environment, also check with hosting provider about the constraints placed on DB

Comment: 3. Example sex - M,F,T will do. you don't need 6 chars on that. That's one. Similarly check for other fields in all tables.______
4. When you have DOB, Age is computable. Don't repeat. It's again mix of functional & technical decision_______
5. In the screenshot the "NULL" vertical shows all NO. It most likely means that all fields are mandatory. Do you seriously expect religion and tribe to be provided for every patient? Please check with basic requirement. Without a good requirement document, your system is headed nowhere

Comment: I have one more suggestion: Hire a good DB expert to design the system.

Comment: in case of point 5, even if I set NULL as default for non compulsory fields, my insert query will remove the NULL thing. What will I be doing in that case?

Comment: Check the sql query i am using to insert the records into database table, wont this query be removing the NULL values in the table? How will I keep the NULL values in that case?

Comment: as long as there is some data being inserted in the non-null column, it should be fine. if $religion is null, it will throw error. you cannot assign NULL to not-null field

Answer (score 0):

I have almost no experience with mysql buth for any good relational db system few milion of records shouldn't be a problem.

Patients in one table and hostipals in other table looks good to me, but you also need archive tables that will monitor any changes within the db and this tables will grow really large. I would do it t with  triggers and store every change on every record (buth I am experienced with Oracle an I am used to really large tables).

Also make sure that no field that would be used for searching cannot be null (in Oracle indexes are not used on null values).